# Área da postagem sendo atualizada após clique

Tags: bug, status-pronto, status-aceito

Não sei bem como reproduzir o problema, no entanto ocorreu comigo e com o @randrade

Após comentar/editar um comentário ou o AP editar a postagem (no caso o @Gabe), ao clicar na área da postagem ela começa a piscar, mas mostra o efeito de "fade", vejam:

> [image: bug]

Tenho quase certeza que começou logo após o Gabe editar a resposta dele.

Note que se eu aperto F5 para de ocorrer, ainda não tenho certeza de como ocorre.

Note que quando pisca ele dispara uma requisição:

[image: Console do browser]

> [Posts disappear briefly then reload when I click them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283925/198279)

Comment: Tem esse e outros comportamentos meio esquisitos.

Comment: No meu caso ocorreu quando eu cloquei em **"mostrar mais N comentários"**. O resultado pode ser visto [neste gif](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nS7JP.gif). Ressalto que não consegui recriar esse comportamento.

Comment: aconteceu comigo hoje tentando postar uma resposta. Fui tentar copiar um trecho da pergunta, minha resposta "postou" no meio.

Comment: Isso é um bug em todo o Stack Exchange. No Meta do SO matriz tem alguns posts sobre isso também.

Comment: O Marc tá dando uma olhada

Comment: @Gabe pode ser isto http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284005/198279 ?

Comment: Isso está se repetindo no site principal também. Acabou de acontecer comigo ao votar em uma resposta.

Comment: Guilerme, apenas para dar mais informações, a url chamada é: `http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/ajax-load-realtime/150470?title=true&_=1472758064143`. Lembrando que o id da pergunta muda.

Comment: Para ser mais específico, [esta imagem](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ9AY.png) mostra o **Header** e demais informações.

Comment: @Randrade ótimo, bem mais complementar.